# How to Apply Styling to particular Cell table Row?

Tags: java, css, gwt

I Would like to apply background color to particular cell table row element based on some condition, I found one API method 
 `getRowElement(rowNo).getStyle().setBackgroundColor`

```
public void setRowStyleCell(final int rowNo){
    getRowElement(rowNo).getStyle().setBackgroundColor(style);
}
```

but its not taking this styling because of some other styling(Pseudocode Styling) which is already applied to this cell table(got high priority).

```
tr:nth-child(odd){background:none !important;}

tr:nth-child(even) {background:none !important;}
```

Is there any way to override this styling in gwt?

Comment: Apply inline style with important

Comment: How to Apply?any example?I need to apply only back ground color to cell table row.

Comment: How to Add inline Styling to cell table row element?

Answer (score 0):

Override getCellStuleNames and return the style you want.

TextColumn nameColumn= new TextColumn() {

```
            @Override
           public String getCellStyleNames(Context context, Object  object) {
                 return "styleName"; //The name of style id
             }  

            @Override
            public String  getValue(Object object) {                                         
                return object.getName();
            }           

          };
```

Comment: i am applying Pseudocode Styling to the row element which is got high priority than applying styles to the particular row.Only way is to set inline styling(I dont no how to set inline styling to particular row element).